# image size is not fitting in div

Tags: html, css

I have to fit my div size is `height=250px` and `width=1000px` and want to fit image automatically in this size. but when i upload image it not fits in div.

My code is here:

**css**

```css
#main {
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.promo-image {
  margin:0 0 8px;
}
.promo-image img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**html**:

```php
<main id="main" role="main">
  <div class="promo-img">
    <?php
      $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM adverts_top ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
      $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
      $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $link4 = $row4['link_url'];

      $images4 = $row4['imagepath'];
      $immg4 = basename($images4);
      $imagee4 = "adverts"."/".$immg4;

      $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if ($rowc>=1) {
        echo "
            <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>
             ";
      }
      else {
            echo "";
      }
   ?>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: use `width:100%` in `<img>`

Comment: please which position in <img>

Comment: inn css or in echo?

Comment: Refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38823845/4119808

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `width:100%` in `<img>` you can use inline css as well as you can write it in external file

**Inline**

```
<a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4'; style="width:100%"></a>
```

**External**

Pass a class in `<img>` and write css according to that

```
<a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4'; class="fullWidth"></a>

.fullWidth{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: What are `;` after attributes in your HTML?

Comment: @Kermani it means nothing in html but i didn't mentioned it assuming mohsin_sharif57 may be need it in php.

Comment: i applied this in line css. but when i run my website. my website not run.

Comment: echo " <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';style="width:100%"></a>";   when i add this style my website not runs.my website is http://seeknfame.com/    but when i remove style="width:100%" from this. than my site runs

Comment: try writing style before src `<a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img style="width:100%" src='$imagee4';></a>`

Comment: on which image you are using this css

Answer (score 0):

I think he means this

```
.promo-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0;
}
```

seeing how he set `#main`'s position to relative without setting any other values (like `top` or `left`) for `#main`